# Accessing Localhost hosted on one virtual machine by another virtual machine

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, nat

**Background:**

> On my *Windows 7* machine I have a web
>   development virtual machine running
>   *Ubuntu*.  The VM's network structure is set to NAT (as opposed to bridge,
>   etc.).  I run additional virtual
>   machines of *XP* with different IE
>   browsers on them for testing.

**My Question:**

> I know that when using NAT on a
>   virtual machine, you are able to
>   access the web server from the host
>   inside of a virtual machine by
>   directing a web browser to [10.0.2.2](http://10.0.2.2). 
>   If http://localhost is hosted on
>   **Virtual Machine A** (*Ubuntu*).  How do I access that from **Virtual
>   Machine B** (any *XP* VM)?

**Edit:**

> I am looking for an elegant solution,
>   similar to that of using [10.0.2.2](http://10.0.2.2) as
>   described above.  I would prefer not
>   to have to specify dynamic IP's for
>   the VM's as well as not having to look
>   up the VM's IP every time I want to
>   access it.  Is anything like this
>   possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the IP address of  VM A instead of localhost in the browser of VM B.

This assumes theres no firewall rules preventing it from being accessed.

Its worth doing a ping test from VM B first to eliminate any other issues first.

Comment: Yes, that is a solution.  However, I was hoping for a more elegant (static IP) solution.  Similar to that of using 10.0.2.2 for NAT access in the virtual machine.  I'm sorry for not mentioning this in the original question... I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry all I would do is give VM A a static IP address and put an entry in the localhost file on VM B but if you need to stick to NAT I am not sure what you can do.